# Forcing Eclipse to showing only errors

Tags: java, eclipse

Is it possible to tell Eclipse to show only errors in the console ?

It could be useful as I'm using external libraries that use the output to display unwanted data. I know that there is a button "Show Console when standard error changes", but, I'm looking for a filter rather.

Regards.

Comment: What kind of logging is used? Each implementation has its own way of increasing the logging level per package/class

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse (the `Console` view) shows two different outputs: The standard output (`System.out`) and the error output (`System.err`). Eclipse itself cannot distinguish between an actual error/exception logged by your programm running, and an external library which writes it copyright/licence information to the error stream.

Comment: This looks like more of a comment to me, than an answer. I think his question needs additional clarity (what "errors" is he trying to hide?) but I don't think an answer is the place to suggest that

Comment: I think I know what he's talking about. Tity uses an external library which writes something to the error stream, but it is rather an information for the user that the library is e.g. must not be used for commercial use, because it is an evaluation version only (or something like that). So its just an information from the external library written to the error stream, than an error/exception.

Comment: In either case, this isn't an answer. He's asking how he may disable that. If he's using a dependency that _directly_ writes to `System.out` or `System.err`, he needs to dump that dependency yesterday. Logging libraries exist for this reason, and there is probably a way he can stop this output

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the System.out and/or System.err to another OutputStream using the System.setOut and System.setErr functions. This way you can create your own "Console view" or handle the output yourself. If you implement your custom OutputStream class, you can also send the data to the original OutputStream (original System.out or System.err).

```
PrintStream oldOut;

oldOut = System.out;
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {
    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        // handle the "b" or
        // send it to old stdout:
        oldOut.write(b);
    }
}));

// do what you want with the stream and afterwards
System.setOut(oldOut);
```

Also be aware that it may be a problem if you do it in the UI thread. For me the application always hanged afterwards.

If you redirect these streams you can decide if you will forward it onto the standard output/error.